# How to use the gets() command to take text input and display output using printf statement in c language?

Tags: c, printf, gets

I want a program for c language that takes text input using gets() function,...and then, prints the same text using print f statement.please answer! :)

Comment: Don't use `gets`, use `fgets` instead. Beyond that, you just need to find the documentation for the functions, and a good book about the C language, and start reading. (Not my down vote, btw.)

Comment: "I want a program that takes text input using gets() function" - no, you don't. Really. [Read **this**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets), particularly the Notes section. You can stop reading as soon as you see the single line that states: "Never use gets()."

Comment: Hands up and gimme the codez!  NOW!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char str[50];

   printf("Enter a string : ");
   gets(str);

   printf("You entered: %s", str);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: **Do not use `gets`!**

Comment: Since C99, `gets()` was depreciated.  Since C11, `gets()` is no longer part of the standard library.  Better to use `char str[50]; fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin); str[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';`  to approximate `gets()` functionality